# Remove the space between two words in PHP

Tags: php, string

I am developing a website in PHP. In it, I am saving the images in a folder on a server.

I accept a name from user and want to use that name as the image name. Sometimes the user enters a name like two words.

So I want to remove the space between two words.
For example, if the user enters as 'Paneer Pakoda dish', I want to convert it like 'PaneerPakodaDish'.

How can I do that?

I used

```
1) str_replace(' ', '', $str);

2) preg_replace(' ', '', $str);

3) trim($str, ' ');
```

But these are not giving the output as I required.

Comment: ok, what's wrong with your second attempt?

Comment: You forget php delimiters, try `preg_replace('~ ~','',$str);`

Comment: 3) wont work in your example, but 1) and 2) should work

Comment: Please mention what output you want ?

Comment: The First one is working whats wrong with `str_replace` can you elaborate.

Comment: I accept input from user like : ' Paneer Pakoda    Spicy Dish ' and want output like 'PaneerPakodaSpicyDish' and save as image name .

Comment: Above function gives output like 'Panner Pakoda Spicy Dish'. It remove only extra space but not concat the words

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'PaneerPakodaDish' should be the desired output.

```
$string = 'Paneer Pakoda dish';
$s = ucfirst($string);
$bar = ucwords(strtolower($s));
echo $data = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $bar);
```

It will give you the exact output 'PaneerPakodaDish' where character "D" will also be in capital.

Answer (score 18):

```
<?php
    $str = "Paneer Pakoda dish";
    echo str_replace(' ', '', $str);
?>
```

Comment: Much better than a regular expression for this simple task

Comment: yes it replace only white space.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Its duplicate one of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34735829/remove-the-space-between-two-words-in-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34735829/remove-the-space-between-two-words-in-php) even though you didn't closed the question

Answer (score 4):

The code below should work

```
<?php
    $test = "My Name is Amit";
    echo preg_replace("/\s+/", "", $test);
?>
```

Comment: no, need for `i` modifier...

Comment: Yes, @AvinashRaj no need for i modifier as it is space.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
    $char = "Lorem Ipsum Amet";
    echo str_replace(' ', '', $char);
?>
```

The result will look like this: LoremIpsumAmet

Comment: What happens if there are 2 spaces between the words?

Comment: @Mirko :  pass double space in str_replace ex-  str_replace('  ', '', $char);

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
echo str_replace(' ', '', $str);
```

`trim()` should be used to remove white space at the front and back end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Please try "preg_replace" for remove space between words.

```
$string = "Paneer Pakoda dish";
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
echo $string;
```