# How to remove space?

Tags: php

code:

```
$filename = 'college_logo/'.$college_name22[0].'.jpg';
echo $filename;
```

In this code I want to remove space between two words. here when I echo $filename it print `college_logo/Christian Medical College, Vellore .jpg` 
In this name having space between (vellore .jpg) but I want (vellore.jpg)
how can I fix this problem ?

Thank You

Comment: `trim($college_name22[0]);`

Comment: `str_replace( ' ','', $filename )`?

Comment: If you are having spaces in filename you should `escape` them instead of removing it.

Comment: You can use trim function.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34735829/remove-the-space-between-two-words-in-php

Comment: do you want to remove all spaces or just the one at the end?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to strip all spaces out of a string in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109325/how-to-strip-all-spaces-out-of-a-string-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change from

```
$filename = 'college_logo/'.$college_name22[0].'.jpg';
```

to

```
$filename = 'college_logo/'.trim($college_name22[0]).'.jpg';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace spaces width underscore "_" using  `str_replace(" ", "_",$filename);`

```
$filename = 'college_logo/'.$college_name22[0].'.jpg';
$filename = str_replace(" ", "_",$filename);
echo $filename;
```